# Laravel- Get first element from hasMany realtion?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get first element every category.

```
Category Class 

public function product()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}

public function first_product()
{
   return $this->product()->limit(1);
}
```

Here is my query

```
 $categories = Category::with('first_product')->get();
```

I got first product only first element of category. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [hasOne()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) to get single data

```php
public function first_product()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Product::class);
}
```

then

```php
 $categories = Category::with('first_product')->get();
```

Comment: Thank for your response. It throw this error: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\Models\Product::addEagerConstraints() in file /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php on line 50

Comment: When I used this query. it will return only last element with product? why?